# Having problems interpreting and implementing radial distortion correction

Tags: math, computer-vision, formula, camera-calibration

I am trying to implement the radial distortion correction from this technical report: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/tr98-71.pdf

I am having quite a few problems interpreting/understanding the equations in the report. The equations of interest are number 11 and 12 with the matrix formulation provided just afterwards.

The problem I am having is that its really unclear as to what the descriptions of some of the variables actually mean.

If we look at the descriptions of [u,v] and [x,y], in the technical report it states that [u,v] are the pixel image coordinates and that [x,y] are the normalised image coordinates. My intuitive understanding of this is that [x,y] = [u,v] – [principal point] but then the presence of the [u-u_0] term would be redundant if that was correct.

I so far have been able to determine the intrinsic parameters of a camera and the only thing perventing me doing distortion correction is my understanding of the equations.

Comment: Pretty sure that normalised coordinates are the pixel coordinates divided by some multiple of the image dimensions (+ maybe a constant factor)

Answer (score 0):

The steps are clearly laid out in the documentation of the OpenCV rooutines implementing Zhang's method. Please see the "Detailed Description" section [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html)